# Quarkus discovery with consul

Tags: microservices, quarkus, consul

I created Microservice using Quarkus and assigned random port. But i need to register this service with consul.

I did't find any documentation for this requirement. Please anyone help me.

Thank you.

Comment: did you try [this doc](https://quarkus.io/guides/stork#service-registration-in-consul)

Comment: Thank you for your response. i was able to register with consul with this code.

Answer (score 0):

You can find example consule registration code

```java
package org.acme.services;

import io.quarkus.runtime.StartupEvent;
import io.vertx.ext.consul.ServiceOptions;
import io.vertx.mutiny.ext.consul.ConsulClient;
import io.vertx.ext.consul.ConsulClientOptions;
import io.vertx.mutiny.core.Vertx;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.config.inject.ConfigProperty;

import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.enterprise.event.Observes;

@ApplicationScoped
public class Registration {

    @ConfigProperty(name = "consul.host") String host;
    @ConfigProperty(name = "consul.port") int port;

    @ConfigProperty(name = "red-service-port", defaultValue = "9000") int red;
    @ConfigProperty(name = "blue-service-port", defaultValue = "9001") int blue;

    /**
     * Register our two services in Consul.
     *
     * Note: this method is called on a worker thread, and so it is allowed to block.
     */
    public void init(@Observes StartupEvent ev, Vertx vertx) {
        ConsulClient client = ConsulClient.create(vertx, new ConsulClientOptions().setHost(host).setPort(port));

        client.registerServiceAndAwait(
                new ServiceOptions().setPort(red).setAddress("localhost").setName("my-service").setId("red"));
        client.registerServiceAndAwait(
                new ServiceOptions().setPort(blue).setAddress("localhost").setName("my-service").setId("blue"));
    }
}
```

for full details please [check](https://quarkus.io/guides/stork#service-registration-in-consul)

Answer (score 0):

I am able to register the service into consul using the following code.

My challenge is when the consul service stop and restart, this application is not reregister into consul.

How to do it ?

```
package com.example;

import io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus;
import io.quarkus.runtime.QuarkusApplication;
import io.quarkus.runtime.annotations.QuarkusMain;
import io.vertx.core.Vertx;
import io.vertx.ext.consul.ConsulClient;
import io.vertx.ext.consul.ConsulClientOptions;
import io.vertx.ext.consul.ServiceOptions;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.config.inject.ConfigProperty;

import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.CDI;
import javax.inject.Inject;

@QuarkusMain
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Quarkus.run(MyApp.class, args);
    }

    public static class MyApp implements QuarkusApplication {

        @ConfigProperty(name = "quarkus.http.port")
        String port;

        @ConfigProperty(name = "consul-host")
        String consulHost;

        @ConfigProperty(name = "consul-port")
        String consulPort;

        @Inject
        Vertx vertx;

        @Override
        public int run(String... args) throws Exception {
            ConsulClient client = ConsulClient.create(vertx,
                    new ConsulClientOptions().setHost(consulHost).setPort(Integer.parseInt(consulPort)));

            client.registerServiceAndAwait(
                    new ServiceOptions().setPort(Integer.parseInt(port)).setName("auth-service")
                            .setId("auth-service-" + port));

            Quarkus.waitForExit();
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```